# RubyGems install Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I am trying to install Ruby and I'm running into issues installing RubyGems following this guide: http://rubygems.org/pages/download

When I run setup.rb I get the below output?

```
C:\ruby\rubygems-1.7.2\rubygems-1.7.2>ruby setup.rb
./lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for futur
e version
./lib/rubygems/dependency.rb:203: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future v
ersion
./lib/rubygems/dependency.rb:204: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future v
ersion
./lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:56:in `require': undefined method `end_with?' f
or "no such file to load -- psych":String (NoMethodError)
    from ./lib/rubygems.rb:720:in `load_yaml'
    from ./lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:231:in `load_file'
    from ./lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:178:in `initialize'
    from ./lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:77:in `new'
    from ./lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:77:in `do_configuration'
    from ./lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:50:in `run'
    from setup.rb:35
```

Note I have installed Ruby using the 1.86 installer following this guide: http://gojko.net/2010/01/01/bdd-in-net-with-cucumber-cuke4nuke-and-teamcity/

Scream novice!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby 1.8.6 is terribly outdated I belive. Unless you need it for compatibility reasons you should consider using ruby 1.9.2 (which is now recommended) or 1.8.7 at the very least. Alternatively you may try using older rubygems but then you may run into problems further down the way.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the version after talking to a colleague, FYI anyone  http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
From this link :  RubyInstallers download Ruby 1.8.6-p398
From this link : Development Kit download devkit-3.4 5r3-20091110.7z.